# What is the field of moduli?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I encountered when reading material around elliptic curves the notion of " Field of moduli". I tried to search for it but didn't any text explaining what the term means.

Could anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Look at the second slide of http://icerm.brown.edu/materials/Slides/sp-s12-w3/Variations_on_a_Theme-Fields_of_Definition,_Fields_of_Moduli,_Automorphisms,_and_Twists_%5D_Michelle_Manes,_University_of_Hawaii.pdf

Comment: I was just reading this, it might help: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610247v1.pdf